# Teradata LEFT() function issue

Tags: teradata

I run the following query against Teradata using SAS, and it works fine

```
SELECT LEFT(first_name,7) 
FROM testTab
```

However, when I run the same query in `Sql Assistant` it throws an error : `Expected something between keyword SELECT and keyword LEFT`.

On my other computer, the above code runs on `Sql Assistant`.

So, my question is, why does the `LEFT` function work sometimes, and sometimes it doesn't ?

**There are a lot of workarounds, but I want to know what the hell is going on with this `LEFT` function ?**

Comment: Check if you have connected to Teradata in TERADATA or ANSI mode.

Comment: Thank you . How to check it with Sql Assistant ?

Comment: It is a setting the Teradata ODBC connection definition.  The command `HELP SESSION` will show it, but I am not sure if that alone is the reason it would work for some connections and not others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how the SAS version was running as `LEFT` is not a function in Teradata. `LEFT` is a keyword in Teradata because of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Perhaps SAS has some sort of parser/rewrite thing that changes it over to proper Teradata function.

At any rate, to do this in Teradata you can do:

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING(first_name FROM 1 FOR 7) FROM testtab
```

Comment: Thank you. There are plenty of workarounds. I am only interested in knowing WHY IS THIS happening ? What on earth is this `LEFT` function that I can't find in the documentation ? How come it works in the first place ?

Comment: My guess is that SAS has functions built in that may differ from Teradata and that SAS rewrites queries before submitting to Teradata. I know very very little about SAS, but I think it's a safe bet since only SUBSTRING() and SUBSTR() do string parsing like this in Teradata.

Comment: Depending on the "Disable Parsing" setting you can also use `LEFT` in ODBC (the driver will rewrite it to SUBSTR). And it's one of the new functions in TD15.10

Comment: Darn it! We just upgrade to 15.00 here. I've been enjoying the JSON stuff, but I was disappointed that JSON.METADATA() wasn't available until 15.10. 15.10 has all the goodies.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround:
SELECT **{ fn** LEFT(first_name,7) **}** FROM testTab;

Note: This needs to be run from SQL Assistant with ODBC connection with following special settings:

In SQL Assistant go to Tools --> "Define ODBC Data Source" --> << Click on desired Teradata DNS >> --> Configure --> Options --> "Enable Legacy Parser"

Answer (score 0):

To resolve, go to configure OBDC -> Options -> check "Enable Legacy Parsing"

Answer (score 0):

Or you can write in SEL { fn FunctionName() };

e.g. SEL {fn MONTH(DATE) };